# ModelSim doesn't recognize the parameter data type?

Tags: verilog, modelsim

Here is some Verilog code that I'm trying to run in Modelsim.

```
parameter Data_width = 8; //DATA SIZE
input CLK, RST;
input [Data _width-1:0] D;
```

When I try to compile it, the compiler complains about Data_width in the last line, saying that it expects an identifier. I could hardcode the number in there to get rid of the problem, but I would prefer to use a variable in case I want to change it so I don't have to change it. How can this be fixed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you posted has a space between `Data` and `_width` in the last line.  Change it to:

```
input [Data_width-1:0] D;
```